# How to terminate parent process when child window closes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm executing a process (streaming server) from within a bash shell that in turn launches a child (media player) process. The issue is that when I close the child, the parent keeps running.

I don't have access to their sources but I was wondering if there is a way to perhaps wrap them in a grandparent script/process so when I close the child the parent gets closed as well?

Any guidance will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: would need more info on the server and child, does the child always start immediately? within N seconds? only when user does X?  does the server start the child itself or the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

The parent probably launches the child by executing a file.  Say that file is `/blah/blah/child`.  What you can do is rename `/blah/blah/child` and instead have a carefully-crafted shell-script with that name.  The shell script can call the renamed child passing through all arguments. When the child exits, the shell-script can kill the parent-process ($PPID).

Something like this:

```
$ mv -i /blah/blah/child /blah/blah/child-renamed

$ cat > /blah/blah/child 
#!/bin/sh
/blah/blah/child-renamed "$@"
kill -TERM $PPID
^D

chmod +x /blah/blah/child # Actually, you should match the permissions from /blah/blah/child-renamed
```

This may not actually work if the parent has done something odd but you might be lucky.

Another complication I've just thought of: If the child process changes its behaviour depending on the name of the file it is executed from, then you are going to have to work a bit harder to make this work properly.

Comment: Interesting hack but given that the child is a system-wide media player (vlc) I don't think it'd be a good idea to rename it

Comment: Can you get the parent to call it from a different path? It's possible that you can configure the parent to tell it the location of vlc. Then you just point the parent at this shell-script.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot specify the path.

Comment: If the program finds vlc on the PATH rather than using an absolute location, you could temporarily add the directory containing this script to the fron of the PATH before running: `PATH="/my/script/dir:$PATH" program args ...`

Answer (score -1):

Usually, you can use command `ps -ef` to check the process id you are going to kill and its parent id, then you can use command "kill -pid" to kill the process you want to kill.

Comment: I know how to check/kill a pid (kill -9 `ps aux | grep COMMAND | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')` but this alone doesn't help much.

Comment: if the question had more detail, then this answer could be more detailed as it will ultimately be capable of accomplishing the task, so +1 back to 0.  btw if you grep [C]OMMAND , you won't need to grep -v grep